# Ubuntu 14 won't update

Tags: upgrade

I'm running ubuntu 14 and when the auto Software Updater launches it errors and offers only a partial upgrade, then errors completely. When I run `sudo apt-get update` it's fine. But when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following:

```
Fetched 60.8 MB in 10min 34s (95.8 kB/s)                                       
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libhttp-daemon-perl' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Any help would be apprciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling package `libhttp-daemon-perl`

```
# apt-get --reinstall install
```

Comment: figured it out but still get the same error even running as root:  Selecting previously unselected package libhttp-daemon-perl.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libhttp-daemon-perl' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your *.list files got corrupted.

First, look for file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libhttp-daemon-perl.list`.

You can check it's presense with `ls /var/lib/dpkg/info/ | grep libhttp-daemon-perl.list`

Then remove this file (or move): `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libhttp-daemon-perl.list`

After that, reinstall package `sudo apt-get install libhttp-daemon-perl --reinstall`

Comment: dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libhttp-daemon-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'python-numpy' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Comment: You need to do the same for `python-numpy` and any other package you get that error message for...

Comment: so i ran that and got the above, same when trying to upgrade.

Comment: I meant you need to do `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-numpy.list` then `sudo apt-get --reinstall install python-numpy`. But errors like that suggest more general corruption, and you may want to force a `fsck`: `sudo touch /forcefsck && sudo reboot` (assuming it's OK to reboot the system).

Comment: dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python-numpy' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libhttp-daemon-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package `libhttp-negotiate-perl' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Comment: did all of the above including the fsck which checked all the HDD's on reboot

Comment: So you need to keep on deleting more packages' file lists and reinstalling them... As long as you get "files list for package ..." error messages, remove the corresponding file list and re-install the package. Unless you have a backup of `/var/lib/dpkg/info`, in which case you could try restoring the file lists from the backup!

Comment: @Andrew Have you resolved the issue?